# Why writing Constructors is good?

Tags: c++

Why writing constructor is considered as good practice in C++ even through it is provided by compiler automatically?
I didn't find any solution
Is the answer is that compiler provide default constructor and we can generate parameterized constructor?

Comment: Duplicating default constructor (or any other compiler generated constructors) is not considered a good practice in c++. Constructors need to be written by hand only when they differs from provided by the compiler. In modern c++ there are ["= default"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Special_member_functions) for cases when you need provide same constructor as compiler ,for example, with different access modifiers.

Comment: I think having a user-provided constructor that replicates the default constructor actually messes up the standard type traits (ex: `std::is_trivial`), which can pointlessly decrease performance when using standard algorithms, on top of being error-prone and inconveniant.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are the way to initialize your object to a valid state, establishing the invariants that other member functions use (and preserve).

The compiler generated default constructor can be good enough (and arguably better than user-supplied one) if all the data members of the class have a reasonable default (and that this default fits the class needs).

Please note that primitive ("built-in") types (e.g. int, double, any raw pointer) generally have **no** default initialization so leaving a class that includes any of those without any user-defined initialization is Bad Thing, the newly constructed object will include members with unknown value ("garbage"; "indeterminate values" in the standard terminology).

For C++11 (or later) code, it's generally preferred to give the default value to initialize such a members in the class definition itself, unless there is a good reason not to do so. This way, you can't forget to initialize such a member in any constructor, they have their default.

For example:

```
class Coordinate
{
public:
    Coordinate() = default; // If you have other constructors and want the default one too
    // ... a few useful members ...

private:
    int m_x = 0;
    int m_y = 0;
};
```

(In real life, you maybe don't want a default constructed Coordinate and want to have only non-default constructor so the user has to supply arguments with meaningful values.)

For pre-C++11 code (if you have to support older compilers for some, hopefully good, reason), you have to write a default constructor yourself for this example:

```
class Coordinate
{
public:
    Coordinate() : m_x(0), m_y(0) {}

    // ... a few useful members ...

private:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
};
```

On the other hand, if you have things like `std::vector` or `std::string` as members and empty `vector` or `string` is OK for your class, you don't need any special care about them, pre-C++11 or post it. (Edit: This is because they already have default constructor that does the correct initialization.)

And raw pointers? Raw pointers also should by initialized (to `nullptr` in C++11 or to `NULL` beforehand) but in most cases, you should avoid them at all. Use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` (or any equivalent form from Boost for pre-C++11 code) by default, and the default initialization to `nullptr` is handled for you (besides many other greater benefits).

Answer (score 0):

default constructors are good for simple types initialization. if you have pointers as members or need to manage lifetime initialization - you need to write your own constructor anyway.

let's simply say: if your class has only int, bool, float, char members - you probably don't need to implement specific constructor. but if you have pointers - then you have to.